# Formatter for metadata property binding in SAPUI5

Tags: binding, sapui5, metadata, property-binding

I am using in my SAPUI5 application for metadata property binding a formatter.
It's returning a string, but the property needs a boolean, so I want to convert it. The problem is that the code of my formatter is not running. Did i forgot something?

```
                    var oInput = new sap.m.Input({
                        id: "oInput_" + column,
                        editable: {
                            path: "{inputModel>/#showcase/" + column + "/@sap:editable}",
                            formatter: function(v){
                                console.log(v);
                                    if (v.includes("false")) {
                                        return false;
                                    } else {
                                        return true;
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: how about removing the curly brackets from the path?

Comment: But I need them, to indicate that I want the value from my model

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes I tried it, and it is working. Thank you! The problem were the curly brackets